# ASP.NET response filtering and post-cache substitution are not compatible

Tags: asp.net, filtering, response, substitution

According to this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2014472 you can't use Response filters and Substitution controls together. Has anyone found a workaround for this? I am trying to process complete HTML response just before it's written to client and I do use substitution controls widely.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an official "answer" from MS Dev Support on this issue.

**Question:**
What is the alternative to response filtering in ASP.NET for modifying HTML rendered by another process when:
1.  The other process cannot be modified
2.  Post-cache substitution must be supported

**Answer:**
"Yes, you question is clear as blue sky and this is officially claimed to be not support. As Post-cache substitution would combine certain substitution chunks to the response bytes while response filtering expects to filter the raw bytes of the response(not modified). So the previously combined substitution chunks cannot be preserved anymore.

There is not an alternative from Microsoft so far."

Answer (score 0):

The page you reference has the solution:

`Disable output caching on pages that are using substitution blocks.`

**Edit**

Possible solution:

Create master pages of all non-dynamic content.  Cache that.  Don't cache the changing content.

Comment: Thanks,but this is not really a solution for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: output caching is an important performance gain that is not easily disabled, especially if it's a busy web site where it can be a great benefit. I'd be interested to hear if some has some solution/idea for this...